# Distribution of $1-e^{-X/b}$ when $X \sim \mathcal{Exp}(1/b)$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

> Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{Exponential}(1/b)$ with pdf:
>
> $f(x) = \frac{1}{b}\,e^{-x/b}\;,\; x \geqslant 0$ and $0$ o.w
>
> Find the pdf and identify the distribution of $U=1-e^{-X/b}$.

What I have so far is this:

$U= h(X) = 1-e^{-X/b}$ which can be rewritten as: $X= -b \ln(1-U)$, $X \geqslant 0$ and $U\geqslant 0$

Then I took the derivative of $-b\ln(1-U)$ wrt $U$ and get $b/(1-U)$.

I don't really know where to go from there. Especially with the part about the distribution of $U$. I believe I could find the pdf of $U$ eventually, but I'm not sure what is meant by the distribution of $U$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note: Since $X$ is exponential (1/b), the CDF is $\mathsf P(X\leq x)=(1-e^{-x/b})$ for $x\geqslant 0$ (and $0$ otherwise).  (PS: This may be found by integrating the given pdf.)

So, by substitution, algebraic rearrangement, and use of this CDF:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(U \leqslant u)&=\mathsf P(1-e^{-X/b} \leqslant u)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(e^{-X/b} \geqslant 1-u)\\[1ex]&=P\mathsf (-\frac X b \geqslant\ln (1-u))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X \leqslant -b\ln (1-u))\\[1ex]&=1-e^{\ln (1-u)}\quad[-b\ln(1-u)\geqslant 0]\\[1ex]&= 1-(1-u)\quad[\ln(1-u)\leqslant 0]\\[1ex]&=u\qquad[0<u\leqslant 1]\end{align}$$

Hence, taking the differential gives us the probability density function of $f_U(u)=1$ for $0<u\leqslant 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now, all that is left is to identify what distribution has this density function.

Comment: @Graham Kemp Thank you for editing. I took $X$ to be $exp(1)$ by mistake.